# Is there a way to open a python document and run it?

Tags: python

I want to make a game for a school project but don't want everything in one file, is there a way I can open a .py file within a .py file for example:

1st file : Congrats, now move on to stage two!

*Open stage two and run it*

2nd file : Welcome to Stage two!

If there is a way I'd be grateful to know Thanks

Comment: Import the file then execute the appropriate function: `import file2` then `file2.stageTwo()` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-make-one-Python-file-run-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course there is!

You can write your code in several Python files and `import` them from the main file.

You can also write Python modules that span several files, and expose only the interface you want from them (a set of public symbols).

Search for "Python import" and "Python module" for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still new so this helps a lot!

Comment: @Nickoo2000 You're welcome! Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can import other .py files as module. Let's say you've one.py and two.py. Now two.py has a function called hello(). So in one.py you can do

```
from two.py import hello
```